# Lower bound on the variance of the maximum of random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, variance, upper-lower-bounds, concentration-of-measure

I'm trying to figure out a lower bound on the variance of the follow: 
$\max_i(x_1,x_2,...x_m)$. Where $x_i, i \in m$ are independent random variables that shares the same variance $\sigma_x$.

I know we can upper bound the above quantity to be: $\text{Var}[max_i(x_1,x_2,...x_m)] \leq \sum^m_i \text{Var}[x_i] $, but what about a lower bound? Also, is there a guarantee that this is the tightest lower bound?

Also, can we find a bound for $\text{Var}[max_i(a_1,a_2,...a_m),max_i(b_1,b_2,...b_m),...,max_i(z_1,z_2,...z_m)] $

Comment: Could it be the variance of one variable?

Comment: @herbsteinberg I was thinking it could the variance of the minimum RV and because they are equal, then it's $\sigma_x$ but not sure about this. I'm also looking in https://www.mit.edu/~dbertsim/papers/MomentProblems/orderstatistics.pdf

Comment: For $\{X_i\}$ i.i.d. with $P[X_i=1]=P[X_i=-1]=1/2$ we have $Var(X_i)=1$ for all $i$, but $Var(\max[X_1, ..., X_n]) = 1 - (1 - (1/2)^{n-1})^2 \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @Michael this is from extreme value theory? I don't recall it has a generic form for any distribution. As far as I know for Normal dist the the max as $m \to \inf$ is a standard gumbel.

Comment: @xsari3x it is just the calculation that $\max[X_1, ..., X_n] = -1 w.p. (1/2)^n$. and 1 otherwise; to add to this discussion, max of $n$ iid standard gaussians has a variance that decays of order 1/(1+log(n)); this answer explains this phenomenon much better than I can, and also has a lower bound for this specific instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229073/variance-of-maximum-of-gaussian-random-variables

Comment: @E-A It seems a good lead! Thanks!!

Comment: Just a suggestion : with markov : $Var(max) \geq a^2 \Big(1 - P(x_1 \leq a + E(max))^n\Big)$ for all $a > 0$.

Comment: @jvc I think it should be $>$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, for $m\ge 2$, there is no lower bound in terms of the variances of $X_i$ (except the trivial one).

@Michael explained that the variance may vanish as $m\to\infty$, but this can happen even for fixed $m\ge 2$.  Indeed, let $\mathrm{P}(X_i=1/\sqrt{p(1-p)}) = 1- \mathrm{P}(X_i=0) = p$ so that $\mathrm{Var}(X_i) = 1$. Then, 
$$
\mathrm{P}\left(\max_{1\le i\le m} X_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}\right) = 1- \mathrm{P}\left(\max_{1\le i\le m} X_i=0\right)= 1 - p^m,
$$
so
$$
\mathrm{Var}\left(\max_{1\le i\le m} X_i\right) = \frac{p^m(1-p^m)}{p(1-p)}\to 0, p\to 0+.
$$

Under the assumption that the variables are bounded by some $C$, it may be possible to get a lower bound depending on $C$ (and $m$).